# Ошибка при преобразовании данных в Integer

Tags: java

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Window extends JFrame{
    public JTextField textField = new JTextField();
    public JTextField textField1 = new JTextField();
    public JButton button = new JButton("+");
    public JButton button1 = new JButton("-");
    public JButton button2 = new JButton("*");
    public JButton button3 = new JButton("/");
    public JLabel label = new JLabel();

    int test = Integer.parseInt(textField.getText());

    public Window(){
        super("Calc");

        Container container = getContentPane();
        this.setBounds(1, 1, 500, 80);
        container.setLayout(new GridLayout());
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        container.add(textField);
        container.add(textField1);
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                label.setText(String.valueOf(test));
            }
        });
        container.add(button);
        button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { 
            }
        });
        container.add(button1);
        button2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            }
        });
        container.add(button2);
        button3.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            }
        });
        container.add(button3);
        container.add(label);
    }
}
```

класс Main:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Window inter = new Window();
        inter.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

ошибки:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input
>   string: ""    at
>   java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
>     at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:592)     at
>   java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)  at
>   Window.(Window.java:21)     at Main.main(Main.java:4)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ошибка в строке преобразования пустой строки к числу:

```
int test = Integer.parseInt(textField.getText());
```

Можно добавить обработку исключения и вынести этот код в отдельный метод:

```
public int StringToInt(String inputString){
    try{
        return Integer.parseInt(inputString);
    }catch(NumberFormatException ex){   
        return -1; // возникло исключение - будем что-то делать
    }
}
```

И потом просто в коде вызывать:

```
int test = StringToInt(textField.getText());
```

Обычная обработка исключения и возврат определенного значения во время возникновения исключения.

Answer (score 1):

Проверяйте что `textField.getText()` имеет хоть какое-то значение, у вас он при выполнении кода вернул пустую строку, поэтому и было исключение `NumberFormatException`.